# Passing the argument through pthread_create

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I am trying to create multiple threads that will run at the same time and will work with a common buffer. When i create the threads, I am confused as to what is passed to each thread when created.

Let's say the buffer is declared in main() as:

```
int buffer[10];
```

When I create all threads using:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread_function, &buffer);
}
```

Will they all share the same buffer from main()? as in when one thread modifies something in the buffer, will it be modified for all threads?

That is the goal, I am trying to have all threads modifying the same buffer and I was wondering if this is how you are supposed to do it.

I also understand I must use mutex locks to make sure synchronization is achieved, as I have implemented that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes. But [side note] use `buffer` (or `&buffer[0]`) in the call. You _can_ do it this way, but if `buffer` were a global, you could also reference it directly. What you're doing would only be necessary if `buffer` were a stack based variable in the function that calls `pthread_create`. Note that the mutex [probably] has to be global, so why not make everything global? To pass _two_ or more args to `pthread_create`, you'd need to pass the address of a `struct` that has the two [or more] items (e.g. `struct myargs { int *buffer; pthread_mutex_t *mutex; };`)

Comment: I must declare buffer and its' size in the main, so that is why it can not be global, so do I keep it in pthread_create as &buffer ?

Comment: in C, a reference to an array, when used in something like the posted code snippet, decays to the address of the first byte of the array,  so using `&buffer` actually results in `**buffer` which is not what you want. Suggest:  `if( pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread_function, (void*)buffer) != 0 ) { perror( "pthread_create failed" );`  Of course, the threads need to exit with: `pthread_exit( &status );` and the calling function needs to wait for the threads to exit via a loop calling: `pthread_join()`

Comment: Yes, all the threads will be using the same array `buffer[]` so the pthread_mutex needs to be global.  I.E. don't pass a copy of the mutex to the thread

Comment: @CraigEstey so in my case of declaring the buffer in main and passing it to the threads from there, would I use &buffer or (void*)buffer in pthread_create as the arg so that all created threads will share this buffer from the main?

Comment: With `int buffer[10];`, doing `&buffer` works, but, stylistically, it's frowned upon. And it's a different type. Use `buffer` or `&buffer[0]`. `buffer` by itself _is_ a pointer [to the array `int buffer[10]`], so that's why `&buffer` is superfluous. `&buffer[0]` is pointer to element 0. No need to `(void *)` cast a pointer to an arg that is `void *`. So: `pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread_function, buffer);` is correct. The reason to be careful with `&` is for more complex stuff (e.g.): `int buffer[10]; int *bufp = buffer; pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread_function, bufp);`